# How do i get a modified Set after updating element for a specific key?

Tags: clojure

I have a Set of objects

```
(def books #{{:isbn 1 :title "Programming Clojure"}
             {:isbn 2 :title "Joy of Clojure"}
             {:isbn 3 :title "Clojure in Action"}})
```

How do i update an object having a given key (:isbn) and return a modified set?

```
(??? books :isbn {:isbn 1 :title "Programming Clojure" :author "Halloway"})
```

In Java, equality can be defined using isbn and the element can be directly added to Set. What is the idiomatic way of doing this in Clojure?

Comment: What do you mean by "Given key"? From your example you have a set containing three maps. In your desired usage example you're passing the set and a new map....but that's not really a key. Do you want to update the map with an `:isbn` of 1?

Comment: I wonder if the data structure can be improved to reflect that :isbn should be unique.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do that kind of updates, you should have an associative structure. But you can turn the set into one and then back again:

```
(-> (group-by :isbn books)
    (assoc-in [1 0 :author] "Halloway") ; 1 is the isbn, 0 means "first"
    vals 
    (->> (map first)) 
    set)
```

This code assumes :isbn to be unique (since you said "key"). It turns the set into a map from :isbn values to sequences of corresponding records, updates the first record with `:isbn 1` with the author, then mangles it back into a set.

Answer (score 0):

Going by the assumption that you're using the ISBN number as as the "key", here's my solution

```
(defn update-set [coll k new-map]
   (reduce (fn [new-set existing-map] 
             (if (= (k existing-map) (k new-map)) 
               (conj new-set new-map) 
               (conj new-set existing-map))) #{} coll)) 

(update-set books :isbn {:isbn 1 :title "Programming Clojure" :author "Halloway"})
; => #{{:title "Joy of Clojure", :isbn 2} {:author "Halloway", :title "Programming Clojure",   :isbn 1} {:title  "Clojure in Action", :isbn 3}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following Clojure functions, update-if-isbn being a non-public function, will solve your problem.

```
(defn- update-if-isbn [isbn k v book] 
  (if (= (:isbn book) isbn) (assoc book k v) book))

(defn update-books [isbn k v books] 
  (set (map (partial update-if-isbn isbn k v) books)))
```